# Problem in taking a string as an Input in JAVA

Tags: java, string, input, substring, stringindexoutofbounds

I am trying to create a program for taking ad IP address as input and give Class, netID, and hostID as output.
I am having a problem in taking IP address as String input in the program.

[This is the snap of the error i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imbmQ.jpg)

### Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end -1, length 0
    at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:3756)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1902)
    at cnPrac6.classFromDecimal(cnPrac6.java:7)
    at cnPrac6.main(cnPrac6.java:94)
```

### Given below is the part of code i am getting error in:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
            String ipClassD = "";
            String ipClassB = "";
            System.out.print("In which category you address is: \n 1. Decimal \n 2. Binary \n");
            int choice = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter your address: ");  
            String str= sc.nextLine();
            System.out.print("\n");
            
            switch (choice) {
              case 1:
                  ipClassD = classFromDecimal(str); 
                  System.out.println("Given IP address belings to Class "+ipClassD);
                  seprate(str,ipClassD);
                break;
```

### Following the the full code

```java
import java.util.*;

public class cnPrac6 {
        static String classFromDecimal(String str){ 

            int index = str.indexOf('.');
            String ipsub = str.substring(0,index); 
            int ip = Integer.parseInt(ipsub); 
            if (ip>=1 && ip<=126) 
                return "A"; 
            else if (ip>=128 && ip<=191) 
                return "B"; 
            else if (ip>=192 && ip<223) 
                return "C"; 
            else if (ip >=224 && ip<=239) 
                return "D"; 
            else
                return "E"; 
        } 

        static String classFromBinary(String str){ 
 
            if (str.charAt(0)=='0') 
                return "A"; 
            else if (str.charAt(0)=='1' && str.charAt(1)=='0') 
                return "B"; 
            else if (str.charAt(0)=='1' && str.charAt(1)=='1' && str.charAt(2)=='0') 
                return "C";
            else if (str.charAt(0)=='1' && str.charAt(1)=='1' && str.charAt(2)=='1' && str.charAt(3)=='0') 
                return "D";
            else if (str.charAt(0)=='1' && str.charAt(1)=='1' && str.charAt(2)=='1' && str.charAt(3)=='1' && str.charAt(4)=='1') 
                return "E";
            else return "Error wrong address";
        }
        
        static void seprate(String str, String ipClass){  
            String network = "", host = ""; 
      
            if(ipClass == "A"){ 
                int index = str.indexOf('.'); 
                network = str.substring(0,index); 
                host = str.substring(index+1,str.length()); 
            }
            else if(ipClass == "B"){      
                int index = -1;  
                int dot = 0;  
                for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){ 
                    if(str.charAt(i)=='.'){ 
                        dot +=1; 
                        if(dot==2){ 
                            index = i; 
                            break; 
                        } 
                    } 
                } 
                network = str.substring(0,index); 
                host = str.substring(index+1,str.length()); 
            }
            else if(ipClass == "C"){ 
                int index = -1;  
                int dot = 0;  
                for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){ 
                    if(str.charAt(i)=='.'){ 
                        dot +=1; 
                        if(dot==3){ 
                            index = i; 
                            break;                      
                        } 
                    } 
                } 
                network = str.substring(0,index); 
                host = str.substring(index+1,str.length()); 
            }
            else if(ipClass == "D" || ipClass == "E"){ 
                System.out.println("No network or host ID"); 
                return; 
            } 
            System.out.println("Network ID is "+network); 
            System.out.println("Host ID is "+host); 
        } 
        
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
            String ipClassD = "";
            String ipClassB = "";
            System.out.print("In which category you address is: \n 1. Decimal \n 2. Binary \n");
            int choice = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter your address: ");  
            String str= sc.nextLine();
            System.out.print("\n");
            
            switch (choice) {
              case 1:
                  ipClassD = classFromDecimal(str); 
                  System.out.println("Given IP address belings to Class "+ipClassD);
                  seprate(str,ipClassD);
                break;
              case 2:
                  ipClassB = classFromBinary(str); 
                  System.out.println("Given IP address belings to Class "+ipClassB);
                  seprate(str,ipClassB);
                break; 
              default:
                System.out.println("Enter correct option");
            }
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Check what `str` contains. I'm pretty sure it contains only the newline character that you entered when you gave the input for `choice` and that `nextInt()` does not consume, and therefore it's skipping your IP address input entirely. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo).

Comment: Second input is not working. write code like this : System.out.print("Enter your address: ");
   sc.nextLine();
   String str = sc.nextLine();
   System.out.print("\n");

Comment: What happens if str passed in classFromDecimal() doesn't have a period in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it is failing is that the code, `String str= sc.nextLine()` is consuming the dangling new line character (when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>) from the previous input. For the previous input, you are using `sc.nextInt()` which is consuming the integer value but not newline character.

Replace

```
int choice = sc.nextInt();
```

with

```
int choice = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in getting input.When you are using `sc.nextInt()`,it takes an integer input until encountering a space.If it encounters space,it stops scanning input.

After scanning integer , still scanner is in same line ,it will not go to next line until we read the entire line.

***So, scan the entire line using*** `sc.nextLine()` ***after getting integer input.***

Here, you can find code.

```
int choice = sc.nextInt();                 // getting integer
sc.nextLine();                             // passing this line
System.out.print("Enter your address: ");  // scanner is in next Line
String str= sc.nextLine();                 // reading the ip address
```

Comment: Another option might be to use nextLine instead of nextInt and then to parse the int after trimming the string. In that case it would need to be in a try/catch in case the input cannot be parsed.